# Get table data in view, send table data or retrieve table data on controller in MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to know how to post table data in view to controller. Now I can create data table but I don't know to how to pass data from data table to controller. Pls !! show me right direction.Could anyone please tell me how to do it?.

[image]

**View**

```
<table id="gridview">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th><h5>SrNo</h5></th>
            <th><h5>stock no</h5></th>
            <th><h5>stock name</h5></th>
            <th><h5>UM</h5></th>
            <th><h5>Balance</h5></th>
            <th><h5>Purchase Price</h5></th>
            <th><h5>Quantity</h5> </th>
            <th><h5>Amount</h5></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#txtQuantity").blur(function () {
    var a, b, c , d, e;

    a = $("#ddlStock").val(),
    b = $("#txtPrice").val(),
    c = $("#txtQuantity").val(),
    d = b * c;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/PurchaseOrder/GetStockData?id=" + a,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#gridview tr:last').after('<tr><td><h5>' +1 + '</h5></td><td><h5>'
                + data.StockNo + '</h5></td><td><h5>' + data.Name + '</h5></td><td><h5>'
                + data.UOM + '</h5></td><td><h5>'+0+'</h5></td><td><h5>'+b+'</h5></td><td><h5>'
                + c + '</h5></td><td><h5>' + d + '</h5></td></tr>');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetStockData(string id)
{
    StockDM data = db.StockDMs.Find(id);
    StockVM inputVM = new StockVM()
    {
        ID = data.ID,
        StockNo = data.StockNo,
        Name = data.Name,
        UOM = data.UOM,
        //CreatedUserID = data.CreatedUserID,
        //CreatedDate = data.CreatedDate,
        //TS = data.TS,
        //UpdatedUserID = data.UpdatedUserID,
        //UpdatedDate = data.UpdatedDate,
        //Active = data.Active,
    };

    return Json(inputVM, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: what information do you want to pass, exactly? The controller method you've shown only accepts `id`, and you're already sending that (`url: "/PurchaseOrder/GetStockData?id=" + a` shows it). Please clarify your exact intention.

Comment: I want to add 2 or more data to data table. but not store yet in jquery. i have record data in data-table only.So how to send 3 or more data from data table to controller. That is my problem !! .Pls answer me.

Comment: Hi ADyson, you know what i mean ??

Comment: which 3 pieces of information do you want to send? You can easily google how to get the content of table cells using jQuery. You can easily google how to include data in an AJAX request using jQuery $.ajax. You can easily google how to set up your controller to accept many parameters or accept an object containing multiple properties. Which part are you stuck with? Break the problem down into small enough steps and you find each part is much simpler, and also a well-known and well-documented procedure which you can research and find examples of. Try something yourself then ask if you get stuck

Comment: Thank !!! I try to find it .